# Actualizar información con ajax php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html5, ajax

Tengo esta simple consulta que lo que simplemente me muestra las visitas de la web, pero quisiera que fuera automático con ajax ya que cuando entro a un post y regreso, no se me actualiza, Aca el codigo

```
$insert = "UPDATE tbl_post SET visit=visit+1 WHERE id=$id";
$update = $con->query($insert) || die ("No se ha podido Guardar");
```

Lo que me gustaría es que por medio de jquery ajax se pudiese actualizar

Saludos...

Answer (score 3):

Hola amigo la verdad me hiciste trabajar esta mañana jejeje.

Aquí un contador con PHP y AJAX puro, que actualiza la cuenta solo si el usuario entro una vez al dia.. es decir no cuenta si entraste ya.

https://gist.github.com/elporfirio/1c9b369426050c8e83b6a9dba21d1e38

Esta todo en el index, solo cambia los datos de conexión en el archivo Conexion.php

;D

Y esto es la función JS que hace la magia, la idea es que llames a tu archivo PHP que hace la actualización.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = 'ActualizarContador.php';
    var divContador = $('#contador');
    function obtenerYActualizar(){
        $.get(url)
            .done(function(result){
                var resultado = JSON.parse(result);
                divContador.find('span').text(resultado.cantidad);
                setTimeout(obtenerYActualizar, 2000);
            });
    }
    obtenerYActualizar();
});
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

podrías actualizar los datos por ejemplo cada 5 segundos, harias la petición cada intervalo de tiempo sin necesidad de refrescar la pagina,

La función que vamos a usar es

> setInterval();

el codigo te quedaria así:

```
   setInterval(function(){
         <?php $insert = "UPDATE tbl_post SET visit=visit+1 WHERE id=$id"; 
$update = $con->query($insert) || die ("No se ha podido Guardar"); ?>
     },500);
```